# Mutable reference lives long enough when function is called directly, but doesn't live long enough when called through an intermediate function

Tags: rust, lifetime-scoping

For the following Rust code:

```
fn facing_of_mut<'a>(domain: &'a mut Domain, entity: Entity) -> Option<&'a mut Direction> {
    component_of_mut(&mut domain, entity)
}
```

...the compiler outputs:

```
error: `domain` does not live long enough
 --> src/facing.rs:5:27
  |
5 |     component_of_mut(&mut domain, entity)
  |                           ^^^^^^ does not live long enough
6 | }
  | - borrowed value only lives until here
  |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the body at 4:90...
 --> src/facing.rs:4:91
  |
4 |   fn facing_of_mut<'a>(domain: &'a mut Domain, entity: Entity) -> Option<&'a mut Direction> {
  |  ___________________________________________________________________________________________^ starting here...
5 | |     component_of_mut(&mut domain, entity)
6 | | }
  | |_^ ...ending here
```

I don't understand the error message because I thought the purpose of declaring those lifetimes was specifically to require that whatever object is passed as the `domain` parameter lives as long as the `Direction` reference in the return value that depends on the memory allocated by `domain`.

The signature of `component_of_mut` is:

```
pub fn component_of_mut<'a, C: 'static>(domain: &'a mut Domain, entity: Entity) -> Option<&'a mut C>
```

...and I can call it directly in unit tests without lifetime errors during compilation. It's only when `facing_of_mut` calls it that I get errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are taking a reference to `domain`. `domain` is the local variable for the argument and is already a reference. `domain` only lasts for the duration of the function invocation, so that's how a long a reference to that value can exist.

To fix it, don't try to take a reference to a reference:

```
type Domain = String;
type Entity = String;
type Direction = String;

pub fn component_of_mut<'a, C>(domain: &'a mut Domain, entity: Entity) -> Option<&'a mut C>
    where C: 'static
{
    unimplemented!()
}

fn facing_of_mut<'a>(domain: &'a mut Domain, entity: Entity) -> Option<&'a mut Direction> {
    component_of_mut(domain, entity)
}

fn main() {}
```